# Creating a MySQL Trigger

Tags: mysql, trigger

I want to create a trigger such that whenever a user is inserted in 
**TABLE A**(*userid,type*) then his *"userid"* along with some predefined *value*, depending in his *"type"*, is inserted in **TABLE B**(*userid,value*)

For example in TABLE A if following value is inserted:

```
userid  |  Type

23      |  admin
```

then, depending on condition `if Type=admin value=1 OR if Type=user value=2`, the following insertions are made:

```
TABLE B
userid  |  Value 

23      |  1
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_ai_tablea
AFTER INSERT ON tablea
FOR EACH ROW
  INSERT INTO tableb (userid, value)
  VALUES (NEW.userid, CASE NEW.type WHEN 'admin' THEN 1 WHEN 'user' THEN 2 END);
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f229aa)** demo

You can also consider instead of storing `value` just evaluating it on the fly

```
SELECT b.userid, 
       CASE a.type WHEN 'admin' THEN 1 WHEN 'user' THEN 2 END value
       -- , other columns from tableb
  FROM tableb b JOIN tablea a
    ON b.userid = a.user.id;
```